# Can Ghostscript print pages in different order than input with -sPageList

Tags: ghostscript

I want to print with Ghostscript pages in different order than input with the handle -sPageList. Though gs prints the pages in consecutive order. For e.g. `gs -o output.pdf -sPageList 1,13-14,3-7 input.pdf` the ouptut is in the concecutive order 1,3-7,13-14. Is it a mistake? How can this be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. PagesList cannot execute pages out of order.

You **can** use Ghostscript to produce pages in a different order, but it requires some PostScript programming to alter the behaviour of the PDF interpreter and is not a supported usage (ie we might change the way the PDF interpreter works, and since its not supported we wouldn't feel the need to tell anyone)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, though with a clunky approach to splitting pages and recombining them:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in 1 {13..14} {3..7}; do
  gs -dSAFER -dQUIET -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
     -sOutputFile="page$i.pdf" -sPageList="$i" input.pdf
done
gs -dSAFER -dQUIET -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
   -sOutputFile=reordered.pdf page{1,{13..14},{3..7}}.pdf
```